# How To: Displaying Alerts Without UIAlertController In Swift

Tags: ios, swift

Iam developing iOS simple login I want to Displaying Alerts Without USING UIAlertController to user when inserting wrong username in the infant of of textfield for example 
How To: Displaying Alerts Without USING UIAlertController In Swift ...

Comment: create the toast view, google it the name of toast

Comment: Why do you want to Display Alerts without using the UIAlertController?

Answer (score 0):

The [Toast-Swift](https://github.com/scalessec/Toast-Swift) Framework will help you, presenting an Alert without an UIAlertController.

```
self.view.makeToast("This is a piece of toast", duration: 3.0, position: .top)
```